# WPF DataTrigger BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Popup crashes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I uses a BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames (WPF / XAML) inside of a DataTrigger to open and hide a Popup by entering a specific state. Sometimes after I navigated to an other view and navigated back the application crashes and the following message is displayed:

```
Type: System.Windows.Media.Animation.AnimationException 
Message: Cannot animate the 'IsOpen' property on a 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup' using a 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames'.
```

This is the corresponding code snippet:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Manual">
          <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="PopupStoryboard">
              <Storyboard Duration="0:0:3" FillBehavior="Stop">
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InfoPopup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                  <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
          <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="PopupStoryboard" />
          </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Do you have `AllowsTransparency="True"` set on the popup?

Comment: Yes it's set to true.

Comment: Oh, it's wpf, change your targetproperty to like this `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Popup.IsOpen)"`

Comment: Thank you for your hint but it doesen't work. The problem is that by the back navigation the Storyboard is loaded before the Popup is loaded. Now I fixed the crash by using a custom Behavior.